# How to have users 'reconnect' with soundcloud on each page reload?

Tags: soundcloud

I'm using the Javascript SDK inside a node.js (Express) App.

Connecting Users works fine, but the connection does not persist between page reloads.
Is this the default behaviour, or is the User supposed to stay connected in new requests?

Do I have to use OAuth token authentication and if so, how can this be done with the JS-SDK?
Inside the "Permission"-Popup, Users are already logged in with soundlcoud, though.
(just have to click the "connect" button each time)

Comment: After reading this thread 
http://groups.google.com/group/soundcloudapi/browse_thread/thread/0892c76ed16f45d1?pli=1
i found some workaround, storing the access token in a cookie myself and setting window.SC.storage().setItem('SC.accessToken', <COOKIE_VALUE>) after page reloads. 

while this does the trick for me, i'd still really appreciate to know if there a more offical way of doing this.

Comment: ...as mentioned in the thread get the access token with window.SC.storage().getItem('SC.accessToken')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, this is the way to do it, officially. :)

For the Next SoundCloud site, we store the token in localStorage (until the user logs out, of course). In each AJAX request to the API from the front end, we put the oauth token in a request header:

```
jqXHR.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + the_oauth_token);
```

Answer (score 3):

Figured I'd share my answer for those who are unsatisfied with the current answers for automated oauth:

Retrieving access_token:

I had to define get and set cookie functions and then I use the functions to set and retrieve a function holding the access token. I'm not going to give these functions for conciseness but you can easily find them with a google search. I then use this line of code to get the SC access token (once the user has authenticated for the first time)

```
SC.accessToken()
```

Setting token:

So this is kind of just an elephant in the room in my opinion that for some reason no one has mentioned. How in the **** do you connect w/ SC using the access token? Do you set it as oauth param? On each call pass it? Well, after experimenting with putting the parameter in every single place I could think, I found out you have to do something like this:

```
            SC.initialize({
              client_id: '[removed for security reasons]',
              client_secret: '[removed for security reasons]',
              redirect_uri: '[removed for security reasons]',
              access_token: getCookie("sc_lm2"),
              scope: 'non-expiring'
            }); 
//Where "sc_lm2" is the name of my cookie
```

Hope the helps! Took me a while to figure this out for such a simple thing

**EDIT**

Using PHP and Wordpress:

```
$json = wp_remote_get("http://api.soundcloud.com/users/[user_id]/tracks.json?client_id=[client_id]");
$soundcloudData = json_decode($json['body'],true);
```

(substitue cURL functionality if you're not using Wordpress). @krafty I assume you would just change the endpoint from "/tracks" to "/users" but I can't say I have ever really needed to grab anything but tracks using the Soundcloud API. Hope this helps, though I'm not sure I fully understand what it is that you are trying to accomplish (or rather, how exactly you're going about it) - are you trying to allow user logins? If you want to explain fully what you're trying to accomplish and the steps you're taking I'd be happy to take a crack at it.

Comment: Oh yes, I'd also like to note that a big part of it may be including your client_secret but I haven't personally tested this theory. Would love to know!

Comment: Been searching for this for awhile, and this is perfect. Thanks!

Comment: I kept getting login screens popping up for each request I wanted to make. However if you redirect after you've authenticated the user and call SC.initialize passing in access_token (which I saved in localstore) you can just simply call the SC.get() etc without having to call SC.connect each time. Thanks for spotting this

Comment: Are you actually placing your secret key in javascript? I can't imagine that is a solution so I must assume I am missing something. I am trying to pick up the user object from the redirect page where my access token is in the url parameters returned by the SoundCloud server but can find no documentation

Comment: @Krafty yes, I am placing the secret key in JS but I can fully understand why that is a bad idea, but as far as I know it is somewhat unavoidable, unless SC.initialize requires less parameters than I am currently using in my solution. I am going to edit my solution to include PHP

Comment: Thanks very much babycakes. I am merely trying to allow signin. In my case I am using Android and I was able to solve my issue. In my case once I get the access_token via the JS SDK connect() I can later make a call using the HTTP endpoint via JQUERY AJAX. I can also store this access_token either in a cookie or for Android I prefer SQLite. Just for science's sake I did try your method with my Secret Key and it actually gave me a 401 "unauthorized". I would URGE you not to make your SecretKey vulnerable.

Comment: Whether it is Javascript or Android unless the secret key is safely being called from a server side piece of code you are leaving your Kingdom wide open. If someone were to read your javascript or in the case of Android for example, use a utility to read your source they could easily grab your SC credentials and impersonate your account from SoundCloud's perspective.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I appreciate the heads up and will definitely be making it more secure in the near future).