# Soundcloud as Oauth Provider: How to make it connect only one time

Tags: oauth, soundcloud, single-sign-on

I'm currently implementing an Oauth consumer service which is going to use Soundcloud as an Oauth service provider as well. But I'm having the following issue with it: Taking Facebook or Twitter example, you go there, you sign in, you fill up the permission form, and you are redirected back to your app. If you go there a second time, and given you are already sign in, you basically skip all steps and are redirected back instantly. That means, Facebook recognized that you already gave permission to that 3rd party service, so it doesn't ask your permission constantly.

And that's what's happening when I use Soundcloud. Basically everytime I redirected the user to the Soundcloud Oauth connect endpoint, the permission form always shows up, even though I already gave permission to that 3rd party service previously. I'm forced to press "connect" every single time, which is a drag from the user perspective (how many times can you give permission to the same entity). My question is: is there a parameter I can use to make soundcloud recognize/validate the previous permission from the user account to that specific 3rd party service? Or is this Soundcloud Oauth design implementation and we have to live with it?

Edit:

Maybe this wasn't clear, but each time I press "connect" in soundcloud, a new access token is being generated and delivered. Since my app uses this access token to identify its users, it doesn't work very well for me that the access token is getting updated everytime I want to log in, making me effectively "sign up" everytime. To sum it up, I want to get the previously attributed token to my account, so I can look up in my database, identify it and log him in.

I'm also looking for a solution which doesn't involve storing state in the client that might get cleaned up.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to have users 'reconnect' with soundcloud on each page reload?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116532/how-to-have-users-reconnect-with-soundcloud-on-each-page-reload)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is store the user's oauth token in local storage and reuse it in future sessions. That's what happens on soundcloud.com.

*A longer explanation:*

When you use the Connect flow, the user is authenticated by SoundCloud (either by using username/password, Facebook Connect, or an already-existing session on soundcloud.com), and then when it is successful, your app is given an oauth token for that user. This is passed to the callback page which is registered for your app.

That token is the only piece of information needed to have the user be "logged in". Unless the token expires (by time, or by the user manually revoking it), then you can reuse that in future sessions.

I think I'm a bit confused about your application's design: where and how is the oauth token being used? I think that instead of using the token as an identifier, perhaps the user's permalink might be better? If you have the oauth token, you can find out the permalink by querying `api.soundcloud.com/me`.

Comment: by local storage, you mean the html5 local storage on the client side? And I'm not sure if that is what happens in soundcloud, because they are not using their oauth workflow, just simply signing their registered user in using email and password...

Comment: nope, it's using the same oauth process as any other app -- i happen to know a thing or two about it, since I wrote that part ;)

Comment: humm... I'm not sure if we're talking about the same thing. When I go to soundcloud, I either log in with user and password, or with facebook account. Either way, Soundcloud identifies me either by my email or by the access token facebook gives back, which is already stored. Now, I don't identify users by email. The soundcloud account identifies the user (the access token). Now, everytime I redirect the user to soundcloud, I'm granting permission and creating a new access token everytime. Which sucks for identifying people who already have content generated in my platform.

Comment: now, this is exactly my point, creating a valid session for an already existing user on the server side, without resorting to javascript hacks. I want to go to soundcloud, connect to the 3rd party app one time, and get a token, and everytime I go back to soundcloud, they give me this access token back (as long as it hasn't expired yet, which will mean I'll have to renew it). It's the part of "getting the same access token" I'm not getting and would like to.

Comment: made a small edit to the question, in case you have some input regarding it.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. My design is simple: My user is only identified by the access token. Everything else I can "push" from soundcloud. For that I'd need to have a non-changing access token, which only on expiration would get renewed. But the problem is, everytime a user loses session and tries to log itself in in my app, it goes to connect, presses the button and generates a new access token, thereby creating a new user account on my app and making its information from the previous login unreachable. This is something I don't see Facebook doing (they always return the same token).

Comment: Nevertheless I like your solution proposal. Indeed I can take whatever i want from the #me endpoint to identify my user (provided it's a unique field) and use it with the ever-renewing access token. I still think that the access token shouldn't be renewed every time on connect, but now i'ts more a matter of opinion on Oauth workflow and not development impedance. :) So I'll accept the answer.

Comment: Now, I'd really like to avoid going to the connect page every time on login and make it more "automatic" a la facebook (if there's already a valid session and a previous permission, you hardly see it). I just think that the end user would benefit of having one click less to sign in, and soundcloud would benefit by being more used as a single-sign-on solution, which would make it a win-win scenario :) Feel free to argue.

Comment: Haha, no arguments here. I'm still not sure why you can't store the client's oauth-token locally (on the client) though? When they visit again (albeit with the same computer + browser), then you can detect (with Javascript) that they're already logged in, and don't need to show the connect popup again.

Comment: same is true if the session is still valid. local storage is a solution to consider for an offline experience, though. But my point still stands.